# Powershell script to get an alert when SQL database properties changes

Tags: sql, database, powershell

I would like to implement PowerShell script to send a alert whenever there will be changes to the properties of databases.

Comment: SQL Server will not maintain notifications for something like that out of the box. You'd need to set up a [DDL trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers) to record `ALTER DATABASE` events, then you could have that trigger write its results to a table that you poll, or a Service Broker queue (the latter can even be awaited). Alerts could be handled by a job that periodically checks the table or internal activation for the broker queue. A full solution is a bit involved.

Comment: There's also [auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/create-a-server-audit-and-database-audit-specification), although I don't know if you can audit database properties with it.